Compile Error when using DML USER_MODE with dynamic sObject new instance
I'm trying to create a new record in CustomObj__Share object via Apex.
Below is my code:
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult dr = ID.valueOf(recordId).getSObjectType().getDescribe();
String shareObjName = dr.isCustom() ? (dr.getName().removeEnd('__c')+'__Share') : (dr.getName()+'Share');
Schema.SObjectType objType = ((SObject)(Type.forName('Schema.'+shareObjName)?.newInstance()))?.getSObjectType();
SObject share = objType.newSObject();
share.put('ParentId', recordId);
share.put('UserOrGroupId', userOrGroupId);
share.put('AccessLevel', accessLevel);
share.put('RowCause', 'Manual');
insert as user share;

I'm passing a recordId and using it I'm determining the custom object and then determining the corresponding Share object.
The above code is just not saving and I'm getting a Compile Time error:

Variable does not exist: USER_MODE

it saves fine if I remove as user from the DML and just save it as insert share.
I've tried Developer Console as well as VS Code and none allow saving it. Looks like a bug, right?

Don't know why someone would DownVote the question.

Did you try the Database.insert(records,allOrNone,accessLevel) variant?

Note also your code won't work because on standard objects, there is no AccessLevel field - it is AccountAccessLevel on Account; see Object ref

Yes, tried Database method as well, same error on deploy of class. And thnx for standard object based correction, I'll make that change but for now let's assume this code is for Custom object only.

Yes previously i also did get the same issue while using "as user" or "as system" when inserting and updating, instead you can execute below to successfully create/update share records. I personally used what is mentioned in the comments.
Database.insert(records,allOrNone,accessLevel) or Database.update(records,allOrNone,accessLevel)
Sample Code:
Id recordId = 'a0QEc00000MktT5MAJ'; 
Id userOrGroupId = '005Ec00000EnrfpIAB'; 
String accessLevel = 'Read';

Schema.DescribeSObjectResult dr = recordId.getSObjectType().getDescribe();

String shareObjName = dr.isCustom() 
    ? dr.getName().removeEnd('__c') + '__Share' 
    : dr.getName() + 'Share';

SObject shareRecord = (SObject)Type.forName('Schema.' + shareObjName).newInstance();

shareRecord.put('ParentId', recordId);
shareRecord.put('UserOrGroupId', userOrGroupId);
shareRecord.put('AccessLevel', accessLevel);
shareRecord.put('RowCause', 'Manual'); 

try {
    Database.insert(shareRecord, false, System.AccessLevel.SYSTEM_MODE);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.debug('Error :' + e.getMessage());
}

If you are writing to test quickly from anonymous window use Database.insert(shareRecord, false);
If inside apex class then Database.insert(shareRecord, false, System.AccessLevel.SYSTEM_MODE);
Note: System.AccessLevel.SYSTEM_MODE this will work in apex classes as it is not allowed on execute anonymous window.
FYI: you will get below error in dev console if you log: Cannot use SYSTEM_MODE access level in anonymous execution of Apex.
Adding part of comments in the main answer for clarification:
When writing code in the Developer Console, you must explicitly include the System namespace; otherwise, you may encounter an error in the "Problems" tab, such as Variable does not exist: SYSTEM_MODE (because AccessLevel class actually references System namespace refer at this article). However, if you're using VS Code, referencing AccessLevel.USER_MODE directly will work, as AccessLevel is defines as global class.
When the code is deployed, AccessLevel.USER_MODE will automatically be interpreted as System.AccessLevel.USER_MODE by the compilers.
One important note: the name AccessLevel is reserved, so ensure it does not conflict with any variable names in your class to avoid unexpected issues.

Your sample code doesn't agree with your text that mentions Database.insert(..)

Apologies for the above, edited the above answer for the same.

Strange. Actually, System/User Mode is not an issue here. Somehow the compilation error is happening if I provide AccessLevel.USER_MODE but it does not cause any error if I use System.AccessLevel.USER_MODE. Because I had earlier tried the Database Methods as well, with allOrNone, and same error happened but you have referenced the System Namespace explicitly which I did not, as it is not necessary to do. Can you confirm if you're able to save without System namespace?

I did write code inside dev console from there it is required to write System namespace otherwise this will show in "Problems tab"  Variable does not exist: SYSTEM_MODE.
If you are using VS Code then AccessLevel.USER_MODE will work fine i think because it is defined as global class there. When deployed it will be automatically be changed to System.AccessLevel.USER_MODE by apex compilers.
Just note that "AccessLevel" is a reserved keyword and it should not match with any variable names in your class.

Actually, I have another org and project where I can save code with no compile error in both dev console & vs code with no need to mention System namespace. I can even save this code with no system namespace if sObject is concrete like Account or Custom Object.

From the above sample code it identifies the object recordId itself so it should work for standard or custom objects. But can you somehow share the details of it would be helpful as it is strange behaviour as per me and as per details stated above. Will research something on my end for this if I find anything will share here. Thanks!
